# How to render raw HTML code in Phoenix Framework?

Tags: html, elixir, phoenix-framework

I'm storing raw html from a contenteditable tag in my RethinkDB database.
Now I want to display the content after retrieving it.

**html.eex**

```
<div id="contentEditableText">
    <%= for %{"contentText" => contentText} <- @contentText.data do %>
      <div><%= "#{contentText}" %></div>
    <% end %>
</div>
```

I can sucessfully retrieve it, but it's displaying the raw html itself.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

The `phoenix_html` library provides a [raw/1](https://hexdocs.pm/phoenix_html/Phoenix.HTML.html#raw/1) function for this case. `phoenix_html` is included by default so you should just need to do:

```
<div id="contentEditableText">
    <%= for %{"contentText" => contentText} <- @contentText.data do %>
      <div><%= raw(contentText) %></div>
    <% end %>
</div>
```

Comment: Yup. Just noticed and implemented it. Was about to answer my own question :) .