# How to Render Raw JavaScript Data in Phoenix Framework

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

I got a List in controller:

```
data = ["one", "two"]
```

I would love to render it in eex template as:

```
<script>
var data = ["one", "two"]
</script>
```

How can I make it, I tried `var data = <%= raw(@data) %>`, only got `var data = [one, two]`.

Comment: Take a look at this Q & A: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31560620/how-to-render-raw-html-code-in-phoenix-framework

Comment: @OnorioCatenacci I think it's different from that one.

Comment: Sorry--should have been more clear.  I mean I think you want to use the _for_ comprehension from that answer in your code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Got the answer from this [post](http://blog.overstuffedgorilla.com/render-react-with-phoenix/),

This is how I make it in the last:

```
<%= raw(Poison.encode!(@data)) %>
```

Comment: If you're using Jason it's <%= raw Jason.encode!(@data) %>